# Replace multiple lines with .net Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am new to stackoverflow (my first post) and regex.
Currently i am working on a simple dirty app to replace baseclass properties with ctor injected fields. (cos i need to edit about 400 files)

It should find this:

```
ClassName(WiredObjectRegistry registry) : base(registry)
{
```

and replace with:

```
ClassName(IDependency paramName, ISecondDependency secondParam, ... )
{
  _fieldName = paramName;
  ...
```

so i need to replace the two old lines with three or more new lines.

basically i was thinking:

find this ->

> className + ctorParams + zero or more
>   whitespaces + newline + zero or more
>   whitespaces + {

replace with ->

> className + newCtorParams + newline +
>   {
>   my field assignments

i tried this regex for .net

```
className + ctorParam + @"\w*" + "\r|\n" + @"\w*" + @"\{"
```

which does not replace the "{" and the whitespaces correctly

the replaced file content looks like this:

```
      public CacheManager(ICallManager callManager, ITetraEventManager tetraEventManager, IConferenceManager conferenceManager, IAudioManager audioManager)
{
        _callManager = callManager;
_tetraEventManager = tetraEventManager;
_conferenceManager = conferenceManager;
_audioManager = audioManager;
      {
```

can u please help me with this :-|

david

Comment: When you type your question there is some information on the screen that tells you how to format your question, including how to insert code blocks.

Comment: What does the original file (before replacement) look like?

Comment: We need to see the actual original text (the relevant portion, that is) and what it *should* look like after the replacement.  Showing us incorrect results and how you got them doesn't help us.

Answer (score 0):

If you're translating

```
className + ctorParams + zero or more whitespaces + newline + zero or more whitespaces + {
```

into regex as

```
className + ctorParam + @"\w*" + "\r|\n" + @"\w*" + @"\{"
```

then you're making several errors.

First, the character class for whitespace is `\s`. `\w` means "alphanumeric character".

Second, `"\r|\n"` will result in the alternation operator `|` separating the entire regex in two alternative parts (= "match either the regex before the `|` *or* the regex after the `|`"). In your case, you don't need this bit at all since `\s` will already match spaces, tabs and newlines. If you do want a regex that matches a Unix, Mac or DOS newline, use `\r?\n?`.

But, as the comments show, unless you show us what you really want to do, we can't help you further.